# Oracle SQL query count group by timestamp substring

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, substring

Given a table that has a column of string "timestamps" (yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS format), I want to substring the first 8 characters, and get a count of how many rows have that substring, grouping the results.

Sample data...

```
TIMESTAMP
20100802123456123
20100803123456123
20100803123456123
20100803123456123
20100804123456123
20100805123456123
20100805123456123
20100805123456123
20100805123456123
20100806123456123
20100807123456123
20100807123456123
```

...and expected results...

```
SUBSTRING, COUNT
20100802, 1
20100803, 3
20100804, 1
20100805, 4
20100806, 1
20100807, 2
```

I know this should be easy, but I'm not having any luck at the moment.

Comment: If you store it as a `DATE`, then you can use `trunc(date_column)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a database to test with, but it seems like you are looking for

```
select
  substr(timestamp, 1, 8),
  count(*)
from
  my_table
group by
  substr(timestamp, 1, 8);
```

Comment: I think that might do the trick.  Thank you very much.  I was trying to do substring() as YMD and then group by YMD.